# How would I use Excel's conditional formatting to highlight values closer to 0 between two columns if there are both positive and negative values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

My goal is to fill or highlight the closest number to 0 per each row out of Column A and Column B like I did manually here:

[image]

Is it possible to use a formula within conditional formatting and create a rule for the entire Column A and Column B results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely is possible with a very simple formula:

[image: Workbook Screenshot]

Select the appropriate cells from `A2` to the last column of data in column `B` and enter the following for the conditional formatting formula:

```dart
=ABS(A2)=MIN(ABS($A2),ABS($B2))
```

Note that if both values are the same absolute amount away from zero, they will both be highlighted.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  When in doubt ABS every cell.   Much appreciated!

Comment: @EmirT Oh, I get it :) **A**wfully **B**ig **S**ledgehammer every cell! PS Not sure if you're aware, but now that you have 15+ reputation, you can upvote answers (and questions) including the accepted answer. To do that, just click on the upwards pointing grey triangle an the top-left of the answer/question

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use this arrary formula first, for example Column A1:A15:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A15,ABS(A1:A15))),ABS(A1:A15),))
```

Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

[image]

Then use Conditional Formatting to create the rule for Column A1:A15:

Select **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule**- **Format only cells than Contain**- Select **Equal to** and select **C1** (Which enter get the result with formula.)- Apply:

[image]

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question.  The OP said _My goal is to fill or highlight the closest number to 0 per each row out of Column A and Column B_.  So **for each row** the lesser of `ABS(A1)` and `ABS(B1)` to be highlighted or filled.

Answer (score -3):

*My approach is little different & versatile to highlight, "the closest Value to a given number with Conditional Formatting".*

*This method will not only find & highlight the closest number to Zero but will highlight the number which is closest to the NUMBER in Criteria Cell.*

[image]

- Write the match value in Cell C1.
- Enter this array formula in Cell C3 & finish it with
  Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

  `{=INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A2:A9-C1)),ABS(A2:A9-C1),0))}`
- Select Cells from A2:B9.
- click Conditional Formatting on Home TAB.
- Hit New Rules & select option "Format only cells that contains"
- From below appeared menu under "Format only cells with" select "Equal
  to".
- For text box next to it click Red arrow and select the formula Cell
  C3.
- Finally click the Format button & apply an appropriate Format and
  finish with OK.

According to the shown example you get cells in both columns highlighted.

Comment: Have you been misled from the OP question by @Lee answer?  The OP said My goal is to fill or highlight the closest number to 0 per each row out of Column A and Column B. So for each row the lesser of ABS(A1) and ABS(B1) to be highlighted or filled.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, it was a different question before edited by Tom and I've posted the answer as it was earlier,,"highlight the number in both A & B column closest to Zero".

Comment: "per each row" was what you missed.

Comment: Check the [revision history](//superuser.com/posts/1332724/revisions). The question was ***not*** different before Tom edited it. All the edit did was to show the image that was hidden.